# ¿Como hacer que una etiqueta select muestre una flecha hacia abajo?

Tags: html5, css3, web

[image: Algo así]

Hola tengo una etiqueta select y quiero que muestre una flecha como la que aparece en la imagen, y que permanezca siempre.

Comment: Es un requisito de la plataforma agregar código a la pregunta. Debe agregar lo que ha intentado hasta el momento

Answer (score 0):

Con este código bastaría.

```
<label for="cars">Seleciona un auto:</label>
<select id="cars" name="carlist" form="carform">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="saab">Mercedes benz</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es cambiar la forma de la flecha, debes hacerlo con css.

Comment: Considera leer [answer], editar y explicar tu aporte

Comment: Si, esa es la cuestion, el como saber la flecha con css